# Url not getting entered properly in mysql php form

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie and developing a url shortner.
I have hosted my app @ http://146.148.29.231/url_2.php
Whenever I try to enter any link in form it's adding "\" before each "/"

eg,I entered "`1/url_2.php`" but in response it is showing "`1\/url_2.php`"

I think i need to use some regex but unsure how to resolve it.

My db is in mysql and scripts in php

TIA

Comment: Can you show us a piece of your code?

Answer (score 0):

i think you want this.

```
$input = stripslashes($_POST['input']);
```

http://php.net/manual/ro/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: I added this function but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem